# HTML form containing multiple 'objects'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Well, i'm not sure if I did format the title correctly, i'll give an attempt of explaining myself a little bit better.

I want the users of my website to be able to create a poll with a HTML form. A poll contains multiple questions, and each question contains 'the question (string)' and a couple of answer alternatives. Thus results in the following structure of the form:

```
Question 1
    QuestionString 1
    Alternative 1
    Alternative 2
    Alternative n

Question 2
    QuestionString 2
    Alternative 1
    Alternative 2
    Alternative n

Question N
    QuestionString n
    Alternative 1
    Alternative 2
    Alternative n
```

I was able to dynamically add the question's alternatives input fields to the form, as well as a question on it's whole.

The problem is, that i'd like to evaluate the form in the following manner:

```
for i = 0; i < questions
    //Store question[i].QuestionString in my database
    for j = 0 j < questions[i].alternatives
        // Store questions[i].alternatives[j] in my database
```

So basically i'd like to have a array of question objects, i'd say. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4):

### Answering multiple questions with multiple answers

You can rely on the HTML form to organise your multidimensional array of data like so:

```
<form>
  <h2>Question 0</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[0][]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[0][]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[0][]" value="2"> answer 2
  <h2>Question 1</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[1][]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[1][]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[1][]" value="2"> answer 2
  <h2>Question 2</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[2][]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[2][]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[2][]" value="2"> answer 2
  <h2>Question 3</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[3][]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[3][]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[3][]" value="2"> answer 2
</form>
```

When this form is submitted, PHP will see an array of questions in `$_REQUEST['answers']`, each one containing an array of answers like `$_REQUEST['answers'][0][0]`.

If any of those answers are not selected, they will be missing from the submitted array. For checkboxes and radio buttons, only the checked options are sent. You will have 0-1 possibly checked radios for each of those first 2 questions and 0-3 possibly checked checkboxes for each of the last 2 questions

Your PHP script should look for array keys in the first dimension to identify question numbers (the `1` in `name="answers[1][]"` and `$_REQUEST['answers'][1]`) and array values in the second dimension (the `1` in `value="1"` and `$_REQUEST['answers'][0][0] == 1`)

### Answering multiple questions with single answers

If the answers are always single-choice, they will always be radio buttons, not checkboxes, so you can do this:

```
<form>
  <h2>Question 0</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[0]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[0]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[0]" value="2"> answer 2
  <h2>Question 1</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[1]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[1]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[1]" value="2"> answer 2
  <h2>Question 2</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[2]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[2]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[2]" value="2"> answer 2
  <h2>Question 3</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[3]" value="0"> answer 0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[3]" value="1"> answer 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[3]" value="2"> answer 2
</form>
```

There will always be only one `answers[0]` or none at all if the answer is not selected. The indices must be specified in order to group the radio buttons together (clicking one should uncheck all other options in that group). This is only for displaying questions and collecting answers.

### Defining questions and answers to begin the poll

For creating questions at the start of the poll, I recommend wrapping each new question input and its answers in a `<div>` before you insert it to the DOM, then you can insert as many `[type="text"]` inputs as you like in that `<div>`. Just before the form is submitted, you can loop through the `<div>`s to modify the `[name]` attributes using the loop index as the question index, but leaving the answer index empty (automatic)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="question">
    <input type="text" class="question" value="Question 0">
    <input type="text" class="answer" value="answer0">
    <input type="text" class="answer" value="answer1">
    <input type="text" class="answer" value="answer2">
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <input type="text" class="question" value="Question 1">
    <input type="text" class="answer" value="answer0">
    <input type="text" class="answer" value="answer1">
    <input type="text" class="answer" value="answer2">
  </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){
  $(this).find('div.question').each(function(i,ele){
    $(ele).find('input.question').attr('name', 'questions['+i+']');
    $(ele).find('input.answer').attr('name', 'answers['+i+'][]');
  });
});
```

Plain JavaScript:

```
var questions = document.querySelectorAll("div.question");
for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
  questions[i].querySelector('input.question').name = 'questions['+i+']';
  var answers = questions[i].querySelectorAll('input.answer');
  for(var a = 0; a < answers.length; a++){
    answers[a].name = 'answers['+i+'][]';
  }

}
```

I havent actually tried those jQuery and JavaScript snippets but i *think* they should work

Comment: Great, this gave me much more insight. However there is a single problem. Let's say, a user enters a question; adds another one, which he fills in, and least but not least adds a third one. Now, he decides to delete the second question.. In that case, the method is not too flexible. Are there any alternative approaches, besides using the hardcoded [0], [1] .. [n] as the first dimension for the array?

Comment: This method is infinitely flexible because you can always edit the DOM. See my edited answer above

Comment: I think this question is still relevant and @vahanpwns answer is the one. You should accept it LaurensVijnck

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I've used Array.push() to help with editing the order of questions, but it should be good to start you off:

```
function Question(text, answers){
  this.text = text;
  this.answers = answers;
}
var Questions = [];
Questions.push(new Question('How many fingers?', [8,10,11]));
Questions.push(new Question('How many eyes?', [1,2,3]));
Questions.push(new Question('Why is the sky blue?', ['Because angels have blue skin', "Because of chemicals sprayed by the government", "Because of the way light refracts into different colours"]));
console.log(Questions[2].text);
console.log(Questions[2].answers[2]);
```

Follow this documentation to learn more about looping through a range of integers in JavaScript (you seem to understand the logic already) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Seems like I forgot to mention that I'd like to use PHP to insert the stuff into my database, hence the reason why I want to structure the data in the form like that. The user himself is able to add as much alternatives/questions as he likes.

Comment: In that case there is a lot more coding to be done. You should create objects to represent an answer, a question, and a collection of questions. the latter should be able to reformat all the data into something you can send in a POST. Alternatively you could just write the form HTML using input arrays and let PHP handle the rest: https://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays (the idea is to use the same name but empty brackets for multiple inputs)

Comment: This is still not what I am looking for. I am aware of the ability to use the bracket notation. If I define one question, I am able to add multiple alternatives using the bracket notation, indeed. However, when adding a section question it becomes a problem, how would I know to which question the alternative belongs? This is why I need some kind of a 2d array.

Comment: you can use 2 sets of brackets. like an array in an array. a multi-dimensional array. i will add another answer to demonstrate

Comment: That would be very appreciated, awaiting your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519952/html-form-containing-multiple-objects/36521561#36521561